# Is there a Tools option on Visual Studio Code under Ubuntu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu. I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu so please excuse me if I'm asking a stupid question.

My question is regarding the Tools menu on Visual Studio under Windows. I don't see a Tools option in VS Code and when I search online I see some references to files/tools but that does not seem to work.

I have tried the option to right click the file in both Explorer in VS Code and the system Explorer but the instructions say to select Open in Command Prompt (or Open in Terminal) but those options don't exist when I right click.

Can someone please advise me and give me a reference if it exists?

Maybe an alternative is to run Microsoft VS using Wine. I have not tried that yet as it seems a little like wishful thinking but I will if someone says it will work.

Answer (score -1):

From the Main Menu, select Help, the 'Welcome' which has Customize Tools and Languages.

Comment: Those tools are for loading things like Python, Lint, etc. They are not the same as the Windows VS Tools menu. The thing I'm looking for is a way to make a button that will run an external script.